# SCIP how to add objective function in my source code by using c++ when I use SCIP

Tags: c++, scip

I want to use SCIP as a MIP solver, but I do not know how to add objective function in my source code. I did not find related code in SCIP C++ example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCIP only understands linear objective functions, i.e., every variable has an objective coefficient that can be passed as `SCIP_Real obj` to

- [SCIPCreateVar()](https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/group__PublicVariableMethods.php#gaadcc57e6efe08c07a23643d0e7fb3151) or
- [SCIPcreateVarBasic()](https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/group__PublicVariableMethods.php#gac0121ed98c509e16fbc4db2bc56cfb51) at creation time of the variable, or
- by calling [SCIPchgVarObj()](https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/group__PublicVariableMethods.php#gac8033a7019d8bd6f9e6889cd2edc4463) for an already created variable.

All example projects of SCIP create variables and set objective coefficients in one form or another. Note that SCIP by default **minimizes** a given objective function. A good example how to setup a simple MIP is the [n-queens example](https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/QUEENS_MAIN.php) in the examples directory of SCIP. This example sets up a maximization problem!

Nonlinear objective functions can be added as a constraint instead, using an artificial objective variable, whose value is bounded by the constraint, with objective coefficient 1. Good examples of setting up nonlinear problems can be browsed in the [Callable Library example](https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/CALLABLELIBRARY_MAIN.php).

Answer (score 0):

The objective coefficient of each variable has to be specified during creation, i.e., in the `SCIPcreateVar` call. You can also change an objective coefficient by calling `SCIPchgVarObj`. Note that SCIP only supports linear objective functions.